# Nav bar with text logo issue , background color is being cut off

Tags: html, css

THE logo in my header area cuts off the overall background color of the header area. I am trying to have my Logo nested in with the background color .

example is [cybertrongames.com](http://www.cybertrongames.com/) has their logo on the upper left corner of the page.

Here is the image i am using for my logo : [Website Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz9mI.png)

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.logo-pic {
  display: block;
}

.logo-pic img {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
}

.nav-links {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 150px 0px 150px;
}


/* This controls that specific A tag items in NAV-Links , in other words the link itself. */

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class=" header-container">
  <div class="logo-pic">
    <img src="/Website Logo V2].png" alt="Logo for website , Picture of a tidal wave">
    <!-- Can style the indivudal logo-->
  </div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <!-- can style the individual links or options-->
        <li><a href="##"> Home </a> </li>
        <li><a href="##"> Game Reviews </a> </li>
        <li><a href="##"> Game Watchlist  </a> </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please let me know your insights on what I might be doing wrong. also is there any kind of specific software or file type you use for Images serving for logos ?

I am using a mac.

Comment: To add code to the question, you simply paste it in. There is also a "stack snippet" tool that allows you to paste in your code and run it in the question. Look for the `<>` icon.

Comment: @disinfor thank you ! i edited my post to include the code, wont show image when i run snippet cause the picture is in my local folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an image without a transparent background.
The better way is to use an image with a transparent background or as a work around you use the css property *mix-blend-mode*

```
.logo-pic img {
    mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
```